# Google Sign-in: disable autologin on page load

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-signin

I'm implementing [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) in my webpage. I have many instances of the button in my page (to unlock features).

My problem is that when an user is already logged, many instances of the `onSignIn` method are triggered.

Is there a method to disable automatic login when the page loads? I want the user to have to re-click on "Sign in with Google".

[image: Login button example]

Comment: So you want an already logged in user to log in again to access details about the already logged in user? That sounds crazy.

Comment: Facebook works in this way. If you return in the page, you have to reclick Log in with Facebook if not explicity managed by your page

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `googleUser.disconnect()` after getting the id token. Eg.,

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var idToken=profile.id_token;
    googleUser.disconnect()

    //use idToken for server side verification
}
```